# Add class to anchor link when scrolling past anchor div - jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a page that has anchors which link to appropriate sections of a page. I am wondering if anyone has any advice on how I may toggle the class of the anchor link when the link is clicked and also when the window/page scrolls to appropriate div using jQuery?

For example, there are 3 anchor links which link to the 3 sections:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</li>
  <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</li>
  <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</li>
</ul>
```

Then there are the 3 sections:

```
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2"></div>
<div id="section3"></div>
```

What I would like to accomplish is when the page scrolls to one of the divs or an anchor is clicked the class of the anchor link would toggle. So if the #section 1 anchor is clicked or the page scrolls to the #section1 div, a class would be added to the section1 anchor link. If section 2, then #section2 link would receive the class and section1 link would have the class removed and so on.

I think I may need a way to track the positioning of each section div and to then toggle the class on the appropriate link, but I am not too sure where to begin.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest finding the total height of each section.  I am assuming there are no breaks in between each section as well.  Then use jQuery to determine the window position.  When the window position hits a certain value, make the class switch.  Hopefully this can be done only with scrolling, so when you click on a link, it will scroll and the previously described function can run and change the classes for you.

Here is some pseudo-code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var section1Height = $('#section1').height();
    var section2Height = $('#section2').height();
    var section3Height = $('#section3').height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(winTop >= section1Height && winTop <= section2Height){
            $('#section1').addClass("newClass").not().removeClass("newClass");
        } else if(winTop >= section2Height && winTop <= section3Height){
            $('#section2').addClass("newClass").not().removeClass("newClass");
        } else if(winTop >= section3Height){
            $('#section3').addClass("newClass").not().removeClass("newClass");
        }
    });
});
```

Again, this is just a quick example.  With more details on your part, I can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help! You have helped tremendously! One additional quick question. Using the height would work, but what if for example I would like to use an inline element <span> for the section? So instead of height would there be a way to detect when the span scrolls to say 40px the link classes would then change? I know this was not my exact question but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a great question.  Without further looking into it, I would suggest wrapping the <span> in a Div.  since a span is in-line, I'm not sure that jQuery could pick up the height of it, though I don't see why it wouldn't.  That might be something fun to try - Just change your html to reflect spans instead of divs, but keep the same ID's and it should still try to work.