# css animate add class when scrolling (one pager)

Tags: jquery, css, animate.css, inview

I'm trying to fire `animate.css` events when page is scrolled (one pager).

Basically I'd need jquery to add for example class `.animate` to every `visible` element in view that has for example class `.anim`

---

Additional points: if there a way to add data-delay attribute to my html so that jquery would parse it with delay

for example Hello

Comment: you could use something like jquery waypoints to make it easier: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started or do you have to use css animation?

Answer (score 0):

Add class to all elements you want to add the `.anim` class like i have done in example `add` 
and then write the following jQuery code

```
if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".add").addClass(".anim");
}
```

and for more details plz check out this [**DEMO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayGwn/173/)

Also check this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864785/add-class-to-anchor-link-when-scrolling-past-anchor-div-jquery)

Comment: Yeah i was thinking the same but since it's a loong page would be cool to have a script with waypoints, inview or something similar that would automate the process...

Comment: so u can also  $("div").addClass("anim"); if your all elements are div ..paste your small part of html to know more clearly