# Scroll effect using javascript or bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, scrollspy

I'm trying to achieve a scroll effect similar to this [website](https://kyup.com/features).

I tried for an hour but was not able to find how they had done it.

I know a similar effect can be done using the ScrollSpy in BootStrap 3 but I was not able to achieve it either with two navigation bars.

Comment: What scroll effect are you refering to?

Comment: The navigation bar changes when we scroll to different sections of the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276166/how-do-i-make-my-navbar-change-css-class-upon-scrolling-past-an-anchor-point

Comment: @calinaadi Thanks I will look into this now