# Change Squarespace CSS on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, squarespace

I am trying to change the background color of the header element in my Squarespace site using custom CSS and code injection.

I found this previous, non-Squarespace [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276166/how-do-i-make-my-navbar-change-css-class-upon-scrolling-past-an-anchor-point/20437992#20437992).

I have attempted to adapt it, but given my lack of jQuery knowledge and how exactly Squarespace uses code injection, I am at a loss.

In the custom CSS area I have added

```
.transparent-header #header { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
```

In the code injection area I have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).on('scroll',function(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $('.transparent-header #header').css({
            'background-color:' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)'
        });
    } else {
        $('.transparent-header #header').css({
            'background-color:' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)'
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

The homepage of our website can be accessed [here](http://www.corey-hill-z149.squarespace.com).

Edit:

Expected result: After scrolling some distance x (currently 100px) navigation header will add a semi-transparant fill

Current result: no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work, just get rid of colons after the background-color selectors.
http://screencast.com/t/qfNoKpSwaRui

Comment: This worked.  Also updated the jQuery reference to the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably handle this a slightly different way on Squarespace using the same idea, in order to clean up your code, release some unnecessary methods, and keep your code tight.

Use a CSS class modifier, then use jQuery to add/remove the class. This way you don't have have to use jQuery's CSS methods.

Add this custom CSS to Squarespace:

```
#header {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    transition: background-color 200ms ease;
    &.is-scrolled {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
}
```

As you can see above, the default state will be transparent. When we scroll down, we want to add the CSS class modifier, `.is-scrolled`, which then add the new CSS. To add/remove the class we can just modify your JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on("scroll",function(){
        var header = $("#header");

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            header.addClass("is-scrolled");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("is-scrolled");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color of a specific page (rather than just the header) as the user scrolls, for example, change this:

```
.transparent-header #header {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

to

```
.transparent-background #collectionIDgoeshere { 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
}
```