# How do I set a js action when the page reach an id?

Tags: javascript, css

Well the thing is really simple, I'm a newbi on Js and know almost nothing, the thing is that I want to change a navbar's style but I just can do it when it reaches a specific amount of pixels, I would like to make it change when it reaches the next div id of the page, this is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".fondoa").addClass("fondoazul");
  } else {
    $(".fondoa").removeClass("fondoazul");
  }
});
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276166/how-do-i-make-my-navbar-change-css-class-upon-scrolling-past-an-anchor-point

Comment: Maybe something like a scrollspy. I.e. the bootstrap scrollspy.

Comment: Can you explain the behaviour you are trying to achieve? This probably explains what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the the distance from the top of the div element using:

```
$("#divid").offset().top
```

You can use it to add classes when you reach the element:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var idLocation = $("#divid").offset().top
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= idLocation) {
    $(".fondoa").addClass("fondoazul");
  } else {
    $(".fondoa").removeClass("fondoazul");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with javascript and jquery below are examples

```js
//for getting window height

var win_height = $(window).height();
//if(win_height)
console.log(win_height)

//for getting window id and scrolling to it via javascript
function scrollWin() {
    document.getElementById('five').scrollIntoView()
}


//for getting window id and scrolling to it using jquery
$( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
$( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
$( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  $( "#five" ).css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 6000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="scrollWin()">Click me to scroll</button>
<br>
<br>

<p></p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p></p>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<p >500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 <span id="five">Scroll happened!</span></p><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```