# Add active class to menu li on scrolling through section in div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In the below set of code basd on selecting the .help-menu elements on left .help-descr div navigated to particular section .
Similarly on scrolling the .help-descr div I want to add active class selection to appropriate .help-menu elements

This what I have tried:

Its something similar to the attached link [Add Menu Active Class when scrolling to div](https://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/MVeGQW) I am not able to replicate same approach here

help.js

```js
// on load of page
$(function() {
  $('.backend-feature li :first').addClass('active');
  $('.backend-head').addClass('active');
  $('.selected-item').empty();
  $('.selected-item').append('<span>Supported Features</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span>Backend</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span style="font-weight:bold;">' + $('.backend-feature li :first').text() + '</span');
});

//on click of backend feature menu
$(".backend-feature-li").on('click', function() {
  $('.frontend-head').removeClass('active');
  $('.frontother-head').removeClass('active');
  $('.frontend-feature li').find('a').removeClass('active');
  $('.front-otherfeature-li').find('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $('.backend-head').addClass('active');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
  $('.selected-item').empty();
  $('.selected-item').append('<span>Supported Features</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span>Backend</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span style="font-weight:bold;">' + $(this).text() + '</span');
});

// on click of frontend feature menu
$(".frontend-feature-li").on('click', function() {
  $('.backend-head').removeClass('active');
  $('.frontother-head').removeClass('active');
  $('.backend-feature li').find('a').removeClass('active');
  $('.front-otherfeature-li').find('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $('.frontend-head').addClass('active');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
  $('.selected-item').empty();
  $('.selected-item').append('<span>Supported Features</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span>Frontend</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span style="font-weight:bold;">' + $(this).text() + '</span');
});

//on click of frontend other features menu
$(".front-otherfeature-li").on('click', function() {
  $('.backend-head').removeClass('active');
  $('.backend-feature li').find('a').removeClass('active');
  $('.frontend-feature-li').find('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $('.frontend-head').addClass('active');
  $('.frontother-head').addClass('active');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
  $('.selected-item').empty();
  $('.selected-item').append('<span>Supported Features</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span>Frontend</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span>Other Features</span><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></i><span style="font-weight:bold;">' + $(this).text() + '</span');
});
```

```css
.ion-help-circled {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.help-row {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.help-menu {
  background-color: #efefef;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 85vh;
}

.help-descr {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 107px);
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.help-menu ul .front-otherfeature-li {
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.help-menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 8px;
}

.help-menu ul .backend-head,
.help-menu ul .frontend-head {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.backend-feature li a,
.frontend-feature li a,
.frontend-otherfeature li a {
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.help-menu li .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.help-menu a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-section {
  background-color: white;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.main-section ul>li {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.main-section p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.backend-feature-arrow,
.frontend-feature-arrow,
.other-feature-arrow {
  margin-right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected-item span {
  padding: 6px;
}

.descr-seclevel {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <link src="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <script defer src="./js/help_page.js"></script>
  <title>Revive</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="dashboard-header">
      <div class="dashboard-left-header">
        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <li>
            <a style="cursor: default;" class="logo" href=""><img src="./assets/img/img1.png"></img>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row help-row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 help-menu">
      <ul>
        <li style="font-weight: bold;">Supported Features</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li class='backend-head'><i class="backend-feature-arrow ion-ios-arrow-down" style="font-size:18px ;display:inline-block"></i>Backend</li>
            <li>
              <ul class="backend-feature">
                <li class="backend-feature-li"><a href="#datasource" id="backend-first">Datasources</a></li>
                <li class="backend-feature-li"><a href="#joins">Joins</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='frontend-head'><i class="frontend-feature-arrow ion-ios-arrow-right" style="font-size:18px ;display:inline-block"></i>Frontend</li>
            <li>
              <ul class="frontend-feature">
                <li class="frontend-feature-li"><a href="#properties">Properties</a></li>
                <li class="frontother-head"><i class="other-feature-arrow ion-ios-arrow-right" style="font-size:18px ;display:inline-block"></i>Other Features</li>
                <li>
                  <ul class="frontend-otherfeature">
                    <li class="front-otherfeature-li"><a href="#actions">Actions</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 help-descr">
      <div class='selected-item'></div>
      <section class="main-section" id="datasource">
        <header>
          <h1>Datasources</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>The supported Datasources:</p>
          <ul class="descr-firstlevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <li>Excel</li>
            <li>Csv</li>
            <li>Oracle Database</li>
            <li>MSSQL server</li>
            <li>PostgreSQL</li>
            <li>MySQL</li>
          </ul>
        </article>
      </section>
      <section class="main-section" id="joins">
        <header>
          <h1>Joins</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>The supported Joins:</p>
          <ul class="descr-firstlevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <li>Inner Join</li>
            <li>Left Join</li>
            <li>Right Join</li>
            <li>Full Outer Join</li>
          </ul>
        </article>
      </section>
      <section class="main-section" id="properties">
        <header>
          <h1>Properties</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>The supported Properties:</p>
          <ul class="descr-firstlevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <li>Titles on charts</li>
            <li>X-axis and Y-axis Titles will be renamed</li>
            <li>Text Properties like font style ,size and color</li>
            <li>Background color</li>
            <li>Grid lines</li>
            <li>Borders for charts</li>
            <li>Alias name for values</li>
            <li>Legends will be enabled only if present</li>
            <li>Color of Chart:</li>
            <ul class="descr-seclevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
              <li>If color is applied it will be added else default color is applied</li>
              <li>If a chart contains multiple color representing its data and if palate is assigned it will be applied </li>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </article>
      </section>
      <section class="main-section" id="actions">
        <header>
          <h1>Actions</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>Actions supported:</p>
          <ul class="descr-firstlevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <li>Only on-select is supported</li>
            <li>With Actions from one dashboard to different dashboard interacts with all charts in target dashboard</li>
          </ul>
        </article>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into IntersectionObserver which will tell you when a section comes into the viewport?

Comment: @AHaworth have no idea on that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add class to anchor link when scrolling past anchor div - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864785/add-class-to-anchor-link-when-scrolling-past-anchor-div-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put an IntersectionObserver on each of the main sections the system will tell you when it comes into view or goes out of view.

Then you can add or remove the active class from the related link in the menu.

This snippet gives a demo but it had to shorten the overall length of the menu area just so we got to see the content below and it also fixed it otherwise it scrolled up and the effect of adding the active class couldn't be seen as the menu item was off the screen.

To make it obvious which section(s) are in view a lime background has been put on the link.

Note, there is some thought needed on what 'active' actually means since more than one section can be in the viewport at once. This snippet does not attempt to tackle that - it's ouside the scope of this question.

The snippet needs to be viewed full page.

```js
const callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const id = entry.target.id;
    const el = document.body.querySelector('[href="#' + id + '"]');
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      el.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
};
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-section');
const options = {
  threshold: 0.33
};
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
.ion-help-circled {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.help-row {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.help-menu {
  background-color: #efefef;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 85vh;
  height: 30vh;
  /* changed for demo so we can see stuff */
}

.help-descr {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 107px);
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.help-menu ul .front-otherfeature-li {
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.help-menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 8px;
}

.help-menu ul .backend-head,
.help-menu ul .frontend-head {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.backend-feature li a,
.frontend-feature li a,
.frontend-otherfeature li a {
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.help-menu li .active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lime;
  /* ADDED JUST FOR DEMO */
}

.help-menu a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-section {
  background-color: white;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.main-section ul>li {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.main-section p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.backend-feature-arrow,
.frontend-feature-arrow,
.other-feature-arrow {
  margin-right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected-item span {
  padding: 6px;
}

.descr-seclevel {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 1;">
  <!-- added just for demo -->
  <div id="header">
    <div class="dashboard-header">
      <div class="dashboard-left-header">
        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <li>
            <a style="cursor: default;" class="logo" href=""><img src="./assets/img/img1.png"></img>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row help-row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 help-menu">
      <ul>
        <li style="font-weight: bold;">Supported Features</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li class='backend-head'><i class="backend-feature-arrow ion-ios-arrow-down" style="font-size:18px ;display:inline-block"></i>Backend</li>
            <li>
              <ul class="backend-feature">
                <li class="backend-feature-li"><a href="#datasource" id="backend-first">Datasources</a></li>
                <li class="backend-feature-li"><a href="#joins">Joins</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='frontend-head'><i class="frontend-feature-arrow ion-ios-arrow-right" style="font-size:18px ;display:inline-block"></i>Frontend</li>
            <li>
              <ul class="frontend-feature">
                <li class="frontend-feature-li"><a href="#properties">Properties</a></li>
                <li class="frontother-head"><i class="other-feature-arrow ion-ios-arrow-right" style="font-size:18px ;display:inline-block"></i>Other Features</li>
                <li>
                  <ul class="frontend-otherfeature">
                    <li class="front-otherfeature-li"><a href="#actions">Actions</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--ADDED -->
  <div class="col-sm-9 help-descr">
    <div class='selected-item'></div>
    <section class="main-section" id="datasource">
      <header>
        <h1>Datasources</h1>
      </header>
      <article>
        <p>The supported Datasources:</p>
        <ul class="descr-firstlevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
          <li>Excel</li>
          <li>Csv</li>
          <li>Oracle Database</li>
          <li>MSSQL server</li>
          <li>PostgreSQL</li>
          <li>MySQL</li>
        </ul>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section class="main-section" id="joins">
      <header>
        <h1>Joins</h1>
      </header>
      <article>
        <p>The supported Joins:</p>
        <ul class="descr-firstlevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
          <li>Inner Join</li>
          <li>Left Join</li>
          <li>Right Join</li>
          <li>Full Outer Join</li>
        </ul>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section class="main-section" id="properties">
      <header>
        <h1>Properties</h1>
      </header>
      <article>
        <p>The supported Properties:</p>
        <ul class="descr-firstlevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
          <li>Titles on charts</li>
          <li>X-axis and Y-axis Titles will be renamed</li>
          <li>Text Properties like font style ,size and color</li>
          <li>Background color</li>
          <li>Grid lines</li>
          <li>Borders for charts</li>
          <li>Alias name for values</li>
          <li>Legends will be enabled only if present</li>
          <li>Color of Chart:</li>
          <ul class="descr-seclevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <li>If color is applied it will be added else default color is applied</li>
            <li>If a chart contains multiple color representing its data and if palate is assigned it will be applied </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section class="main-section" id="actions">
      <header>
        <h1>Actions</h1>
      </header>
      <article>
        <p>Actions supported:</p>
        <ul class="descr-firstlevel" style="margin-left: 20px;">
          <li>Only on-select is supported</li>
          <li>With Actions from one dashboard to different dashboard interacts with all charts in target dashboard</li>
        </ul>
      </article>
    </section>

  </div>
</div>
```